# C# Tuple versus List Considerations

Tags: c#, list, tuples

The different attributes of Tuples and Lists;

- Tuples are heterogeneous and Lists are homogeneous,
- Tuples are immutable while Lists are mutable,

often dictate the use of one type over the other. In other scenarios, however, either data type could be equally appropriate.   As such , what are the memory and/or performance implications of Tuples versus Lists that might also guide our decision?
Thanks,

Comment: I don't think it's a topic for SO anyway IMO they're **completely different** because of intent so usually there is not a _choice_ between them. When you may use Tuple trying to use List isn't _natural_ at all. Decision should be made knowing the content (= the **domain**) and it can't be made _a priori_. Moreover you should consider collection **size** too (and if it can grow up dynamically).

Comment: We generally use Tuples to store composite keys for a collection.  We recently had a requirement change late into the QA process, and determined the least invasive code change was to return two values (ints) from a method (something we rarely do). We used a Tuple<int, int>, but could have used List<int>.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, in addition to what you've mentioned there's the rather significant difference that a tuple can only contain up to eight items. (OK, you can *technically* make arbitrarily large tuples by making the last tuple argument type another tuple, but I can't help but feel that you'd have to be slightly insane to actually do that.)

Unlike tuples in a language like Python, tuples in C# can't really be used as a general purpose data structure. One of the most common use cases for a tuple in C# is for returning multiple values from a function, or passing multiple values to functions that for some reasons can only take one (e.g. when passing `e.Argument` to a `BackgroundWorker`), or any other situation where you can't be bothered to make a custom class, and you can't use an anonymous type.

Since you need to know exactly how many items (and what types of items) they will contain at compile time, tuples are really of severely limited use. Lists, on the other hand, are for general purpose storage of homogeneous data, where you don't necessarily know how many items you're going to have. I'd love to see an example of a piece of code where, as you put it, "either data type could be equally appropriate".

Furthermore, since tuples and lists solve completely different problems, it's probably of fairly limited interest to compare the memory/performance implications. But for what it's worth, tuples are implemented as classes, not as structs, so they're stored on the heap just like lists, and they aren't copied when you pass them between functions, unlike value types. They do however implement the `IStructuralEquatable` and `IStructuralComparable` interfaces, and their `Equals` method is implemented such that this will return true: `new Tuple<int>(1).Equals(new Tuple<int>(1))` (meanwhile, `new List<int>() { 1 }.Equals(new List<int>() { 1 })` is false).

Comment: +1 But add as a note that Tuple(s) aren't enumerable :-) And you can't LINQ over them :-) :-)

Comment: +1 @adkSerenity but I would add that tuples aren't such good generic solution (IMO just good for LINQ intermediate values) because you loose **names**. If you have two integers you always have to rely on documentation to know what is what, a **custom struct/class** with proper names is much more clear, less error prone and signature won't change if you add another element (this isn't true for tuples).

Comment: @xanatos: you are very wrong. Look the example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/orderbydescending

Comment: @Boctulus That example is ordering an array of tuples, and not ordering the elements of a single tuple. `Tuple<int, int>[] tuples = ... ` and `tuples.OrderByDescending(...)`