# What is a tuple as a data structure and how does it differ from a list and an array?

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, tuples

As far as I know, an array is an unresizable indexed sequence, usually with homogeneous data elements, whereas a list is a resizable ordered sequence supporting heterogeneous data. [Wiki states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)
that a tuple as a structure or a math model is *a finite ordered list (sequence) of elements*. How does it differ from a list or an array?

**Note!** This question is not about structure implementation in any programming language. I'm only curious about pure data structures, i.e. by definition.

Comment: Tuples are immutable

Comment: @Sushil `arrays` are immutable too (if not talking of `dynamic arrays`)

Comment: But arrays are mutable in python.

Comment: @Sushil my bad, arrays are unresizable, not immutable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a list, a tuple and an array as data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-a-tuple-and-an-array-as-data-structures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main difference that separates `arrays` from `tuples` or `lists` is `contiguity` in memory and `homogeneity` of its constituent elements. From computer science perspective, an `array` is basically a contiguous chunk of memory storing objects of same nature, whereas `list` and `tuple` can have their elements in distant pockets in memory and also of varying nature. Also, tuple enforces an `ordering` of its element (think of cartesian coordinates `(x, y)`) while `list` is basically an unordered multiset kind of thing!

As an example you cannot interchange `x` and `y` field of a coordinate. But if a region in plane is represented by a bunch of points, you don't care about the order of the points. Depending on the ease of `traversing` or `searching` in the bunch of points, you can use different data structures like `list`, `set` or even `tuple` (say the order is important, like clockwise traversal of vertices of a polygon)!

Comment: Actually list is ordered by definition

Comment: May be, but you have to define on what property the `order` of the elements in a list is based on. Otherwise, we simply say it as an `unordered list` or `list`. An `ordered list`'s example may be a sorted one (magnitude ordering property).

Comment: [Check this out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)). It's not quite about how list elements are placed in memory physically

Comment: Yeah so basically a container containing finite number of ordered elements is a `list`. I guess here the `order` is enforced by the way the elements were appended to create the `list` initially. But still a list is not a `random access` data structure like an (indexed) array, where the indexing (and hence random access of any element) comes strongly from contiguity in memory.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643051/13935289) states a `list` can be a `random access` structure. The main problem here I think is that all this structures are not well defined as pure structures, which produce confusement

Comment: Interesting! I think the practical uses of these elementary structures are so profound that everyone ignores their seemingly loose definitions! Still I might be wrong, a more abstract math oriented person can have a better say!

Comment: I suggest you ask this in https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/. You can have a clearer view if any!

Comment: [Another brief explanation](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Lists) if you wonder. To me seems like I have found out enough

Answer (score 1):

One main difference between `lists` and `tuples` in python is that `tuples` are immutable (i.e the values stored within them cannot be changed), whereas `lists` and `arrays` are mutable. This can be demonstrated with this piece of code:

```
tup = ((1,2),(3,4))
tup[0][0] = 3
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

But when the same is done with a `list`:

```
lst = [[1,2],[3,4]]
lst[0][0] = 3
```

It does not produce any error.

This is the main difference between `lists` and `tuples`, but there are many other differences as well, such as performance and memory consumption. You can refer [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-list-and-tuple/) to know more.

Comment: Thanks, but again, I do not imply language implementation

Comment: Ok...Then what r u exactly looking for?

Comment: you explaining a `Python` implementation, there is nothing new to me here. If you do want to bind my question with a particular implementation, assume I'm asking about common features in all programming language implementations. I am asking about a model of a tuple in computer science, not how it works in Python

Comment: Ok...According to my knowledge, tuples are immutable in all programming languages.

Comment: I think they are, not sure